# What is the replacement in REGEXREPLACE for replacing with matched string?

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

I have a date format `Wed, 09 Dec 2020 10:57:16 GMT`, which i want turn into `09 Dec 2020`.

My matching RegEx is `[0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4}`.

With what should i replace my match in the formula `=to_date(regexreplace(B2,"([0-9]{2}\s[a-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4})","$1"))` instead of `$1`?

I've tried some variants from https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacebackref.html, like `$MATCH` or `$&`, but failed. Using it i get only `Wed, $& 10:57:16 GMT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXEXTRACT` that *extracts* the match from the given string:

```js
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\b[0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4}\b")
```

[image]

Note I added `\b` word boundaries to make sure the match is not in between word chars.

Or, fix your `REGEXREPLACE` using

```js
=TO_DATE(REGEXREPLACE(B2,".*?\b([0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4})\b.*","$1"))
```

[image]

Here, the `.*?` matches any chars other than line break chars as few as possible and `.*` at the end just matches all the rest of the string.